# JSR 303, ValidationException not thrown when using default constructor in POJO

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

The first and second test succed (which means a validation was thrown), but the third test fails. 
Because of requirements of a framework I am using, I have to have a default-constructor for my POJO. As seen in the second test, the validation does work when using the default constructor, however for some reason the `ValidationException` is not thrown as seen in the third test.  **Does anyone know why the third test fails?**

I use Spring Data Graph with a Neo4J database.

```
@Test(expected = ValidationException.class) //succeds
public void shouldThrowValidationException() {
    Employee employee = new Employee(null, "Stevens");
    employee.persist();
}

@Test() //succeds
public void shouldNotThrowValidationException() {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.persist();
    assertEquals(1, validator.validate(employee).size()); 
    //validate returns a collection of ConstraintViolations
}

@Test(expected = ValidationException.class) //fails
public void shouldThrowValidationException2() {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.persist();
}


@NodeEntity
public class Employee {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 20)
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```